# How do I display a list from SQL database when my table is not enumerable? I can use details view fine, but not an index view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am having difficulty getting my Index view to display the values I have from the SQL database.
The main issue is that I cannot use `@foreach (var item in Model) {...` because my table is not created as Enumerable (I think). I run into the error message `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` pointing at `Model` in the `foreach` statement expression.

I am wondering if I need to set my table up as an Enumerable list, then display each item. Or if I am missing something with regards to my Index view. Or maybe I need to pass something through the Index `return View()`?

Here is the Image Model:

```
namespace Uploadimage.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web;

    public partial class Image
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",
                   ErrorMessage = "Email doesn't look like a valid email address.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "Emails do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Upload File")]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Image imageModel)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(imageModel.ImageFile.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            imageModel.ImagePath = "~/Image/" + fileName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
            imageModel.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
            using(LoginDBEntities db = new LoginDBEntities())
            {
                db.Images.Add(imageModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult View(int id)
        {
            Image imageModel = new Image();

            using (LoginDBEntities db = new LoginDBEntities())
            {
                imageModel = db.Images.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return View(imageModel);
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And lastly, my Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Uploadimage.Models.Image>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Province)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Province)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I have tried thoroughly looking this up but have found things that don't specifically apply to me.
Or I don't know what to look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have anything in your Index method which gets a list of entities.
Your Index method in your controller should look something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var model = db.Images.ToList();
   return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Your Index controller action will need to load the images to pass to the view. At a minimum to serve a collection of images as the view's "model":

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (LoginDBEntities db = new LoginDBEntities())
    {
        var images = db.Images.ToList();
        return View(images);
    }
}
```

Then in the view you will need to check whether you actually get any results, then extract your labels from the first result if there are any, or display a suitable message if there are no images:

```
<!-- ... -->
@if (Model.Any())
{
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ElementAt(0).FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ElementAt(0).LastName)
        </th>
         ...
    </tr>

    @for (int count = 0; count < Model.Count; count++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(count).FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(count).LastName)
        </td>

        ...

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=@Model.ElementAt(count).Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=@Model.ElementAt(count).Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=@Model.ElementAt(count).Id })
         </td>
    </tr>
    }

</table>
} 
else 
{
    <p> No Images. </p>
}
```

The above is written from memory so it will likely have some syntactic issues but it should point you in the right direction.

Typically when working with collections like search results I define a view model class for the results page that itself contains the collection of results. The page's model becomes that wrapper view model which can contain details about the page (such as things like current search criteria, lookup values for searches,  etc.) along with the collection of results. (typically a PagedList to support pagination)

I.e.

```
[Serializable]
public class ImageIndexViewModel
{
    public string NameSearchString { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ImageViewModel> Results { get; set; } = new List<ImageViewModel>();
}
```

Where ImageViewModel is a serializable POCO view model to represent just the details about images that the view will display. Often the views don't need *everything* about a data row, and in cases where the data row has navigation properties and extra fields we don't need to display, serializing entities results in lazy load calls or simply sending a lot of extra data that isn't needed.

Comment: yep, copy-paste error from the original, corrected. :)